# How to use MOVE for dynamic arrays with a record as an element and a dynamic array field on it?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi Rio and my program has a lot of dynamic arrays operations. In order to improve speed of some long array copy, I tried to use Move .  For 1D dynamic arrays of basic types (real, integer) I could manage the use of Move, but for a dynamic arrays with a record as its element and this record with another dynamic array fields I'm having trouble to make it work.  The way I' using MOVE for the dynamic arrays fileds of records, after issue the command , these fileds continue pointing to the original source address of the source array.

Testing procedure : array_A is dynamic array of records, tow fileds of this record are dynamic arrays.   After issue Move(array_A[0],B_array[0],sizeof(Array[0]) * length(arra_A))  then change values in array_B dynamic arrays fields, this cause changes in values of array_A too !  Both are pointing to the same address.  How to change this behaviour using MOVE ?

See my code :

```
    program ProjArrayMove;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

Type

     Arrayint   = Tarray<Integer>;
     Arrayreal  = TArray<Real>;

     RECmember = record
           mcode       : integer;
           mname       : string[30];
           mdynarr_int  : arrayint;
           mdynarr_real : arrayreal;
     end;

     ArrayMember = array of RECMember;

     Procedure FillsRecord (var pRec : RECmember; pSize : integer; pFactor : real);
     // Given a pRec , fills each dynamic array fields with pSize numbers
     var
        idx : integer;
     begin
          setlength(pRec.mdynarr_int,pSize);
          setlength(pRec.mdynarr_real,pSize);
          with pRec do
          begin
               for idx := 0 to pSize - 1 do
               begin
                    mdynarr_int[idx]  := idx;
                    mdynarr_real[idx] := idx * (1.0 + pFactor);
               end;
          end;
     end;


     Procedure FillsArray  (var pArr : ArrayMember; pSizeArray, pSizeRec : integer; pChar : Char);
     // Given a array of records pArr  , fills the array with pSizeArray records
     var
        idx : integer;
     begin
           setlength(pArr,pSizeArray);

           //Fils first record - element 0
           FillsRecord(pArr[0],pSizeRec,2.3);
           pArr[0].mcode := 0;
           pArr[0].mname := '0' + pChar;

           //Fills major array with records , each record with dynamic arrays fields also filled
           for idx := 1 to High(pArr) do
           begin
                FillsRecord(pArr[idx],pSizeRec,idx * 2.3);
                pArr[idx].mcode := idx;
                pArr[idx].mname  := idx.ToString + StringOfChar(pChar,2);
           end;
     end;


     Procedure PrintArray(pArr : ArrayMember);
     // Given an array of records pArr, prints each element including the dynami array fields
     var
        i,j : integer;
     begin
           Writeln(stringofchar('=',20));
           for I := Low(pArr) to High(pArr) do
           begin
                 Write('Idx :' + i.ToString + ' ' );
                 Write('Code :' + pArr[i].mcode.ToString  + ' ' );
                 Write('Name :' + pArr[i].mname + '   ');
                 Write(' mdynarr_int :');
                 for j := Low(pArr[i].mdynarr_int) to High(pArr[i].mdynarr_int) do
                     Write(' ' + pArr[i].mdynarr_int[j].ToString);
                 Write(' mdynarr_real :');
                 for j := Low(pArr[i].mdynarr_real) to High(pArr[i].mdynarr_real) do
                     Write(' ' + FloatToStr(pArr[i].mdynarr_real[j]));
                 Writeln;
           end;
     end;

var
    larray_A, larray_B : ArrayMember;
    idx, lsizeA, lsize_int, lsize_real : integer;
begin
      try
          //Step 1 - Fills the first array with 10 records and its relaed dynamic arrays fields with 5 elements each
          FillsArray(larray_A,10,5, 'A');

          //Step 2- An attempt to ast copy elements of larray_A to larray_B
          Setlength(larray_B, length(larray_A));
          lsizeA := Sizeof(larray_A[0]);

          MOVE(larray_A[0], larray_B[0], length(larray_A) * lsizeA);

          Writeln('========== ARRAY A ==========');

          PrintArray(larray_A);
          readln;

          Writeln('========== ARRAY B ==========');

          PrintArray(larray_B);
          readln;

          //Now change values in item of array B
          larray_B[0].mcode := 777;
          larray_B[0].mname := 'B was changed';
          larray_B[0].mdynarr_int[0]  := 427;
          larray_B[0].mdynarr_real[0] := 784.96;

          Writeln('======= ARRAY B AFTER CHANGES ========');

          PrintArray(larray_B);
          readln;

          Writeln('====== VERIFYING IMPACT IN ARRAY A =======');

          PrintArray(larray_A);
          readln;

          //3-Attemp to use MOVE to copy contet of dynamic arrays fields in records member
          lsize_int := Sizeof(larray_A[0].mdynarr_int[0]);
          lsize_real:= Sizeof(larray_A[0].mdynarr_real[0]);

          for idx := Low(larray_B) to High(larray_B) do
          begin
                setlength(larray_B[idx].mdynarr_int,length(larray_A[idx].mdynarr_int));
                **MOVE(larray_A[idx].mdynarr_int[0],larray_B[idx].mdynarr_int[0],
                     lsize_int * length(larray_B[idx].mdynarr_int) );**

                setlength(larray_B[idx].mdynarr_real,length(larray_A[idx].mdynarr_real));
                MOVE(larray_A[idx].mdynarr_int[0],larray_B[idx].mdynarr_int[0],
                     lsize_real * length(larray_B[idx].mdynarr_real) );
          end;

          Writeln;
          Writeln;

          //Now change values in item of array B
          larray_B[0].mcode := 555;
          larray_B[0].mname := '2nd Change in B';
          larray_B[0].mdynarr_int[0]  := 10427;
          larray_B[0].mdynarr_real[0] := 10784.96;

          Writeln('======= ARRAY B AFTER 2nd CHANGES ========');

          PrintArray(larray_B);
          readln;

          Writeln('====== VERIFYING IMPACT IN ARRAY A =======');

          PrintArray(larray_A);
          readln;

          Writeln('==> It seems that MOVE in record fields of dynamic array type does not work as I expected - WHY ?');
          readln;

      except
        on E: Exception do
          Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      end;
end.
```

Thank you all !

Comment: You can't copy with `Move`. That breaks reference counting, as you'd find out if you used full debug fastmm. Each array in the record needs to be allocated and copied individually. I presume that you want these arrays inside the record to be distinct from each other. That's going to require knowledge of the record. You are probably looking for some form of deep copy although it's not 100% clear to me what semantics you are looking for. It is very likely that if performance is an issue, the best solution will involve reconsidering the data structure that you use.

Comment: @David, in the step 3 I scan the major array and I'm trying to copy the arrays of the records individualy, using move. Is this part getting the necessary knowledge of the record and allocatting the needed area individually?   Similcar code worked for the major array but does not for the inner arays in record.  I'm still confused !   Thks.

Comment: The problem is that your first call to `Move` breaks reference counting, and everything you do after that is doomed to failure. You have to stop trying to use `Move` on the outer array. I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first call to `Move` takes a copy of the inner array references but does behind the back of the compiler and therefore disrupts reference counting. From that point on everything else that you do it doomed to fail. You cannot use `Move` on data that is managed.

To do this correctly you need code like this:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    Int: Integer;
    Arr: TArray<Integer>;
    function Clone: TMyRec;
  end;

function TMyRec.Clone: TMyRec;
begin
  Result.Int := Int;
  Result.Arr := Copy(Arr);
end;

function CloneRecArray(const Arr: array of TMyRec): TArray<TMyRec>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Arr));
  for i := 0 to High(Result) do
    Result[i] := Arr[i].Clone;
end;
```

Comment: this is clear, I understood your code and I can now identify where to adjust my program, thanks a lot.  I continue testing and applied move command to 1-D and 2-D Dynamic Arrays of simple types (integer or real) , using the same strategy I used in my above code. It worked for 1D arrays , but it does not work for 2D arrays, I guess due to the same reason you've explained. if youcan, please take a look at this second test and let me know if this is in fact the definitive behaviour of move comand in 2D Dyn arrays.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. One question at a time. You can't edit the question to add new questions. I rolled it back.

Comment: Again though, if you want to scale this up to higher dimensions, with a Delphi jagged array, then use the same technique. Move is just as useless as for a single dimension.

Comment: I was so focused on testing that I ended up putting a second question in the same post, I'm sorry, that is ok you had removed it.  When you say move is useless for single dimension, you mean it has the same performance as copy?

Comment: `Move` is useless for managed types. That's the problem, not the dimensionality. Stop using `Move` unless the data is unmanaged. Although you should be aware that Delphi doesn't actually have multidimensional arrays. It has single dimensional arrays and implements jagged arrays by nesting single dimension arrays.

Comment: I got it ! Move can not work properly on managed types, clear now. Thanks.  I still have doubts regarding the example 2 you rolled back, thefore I'll open another question and appreciatte your help too.

Answer (score 3):

Have you explored internals of copy operation for dynamic arrays  - `_DynArrayCopy` in `system.pas`?

It checks type of all fields of internal data structures, copies simple data with `Move`, and recursively calls itself for dynamic arrays fields.

Perhaps you final result will be alike this.