# How to use move on 2-Dimension Dynamic Arrays of integer/real?

Tags: arrays, delphi, move, dynamic-arrays

In my Delphi Rio application I use a lot of 2 dimensions Dynamic Arrays.  In order to speed up some operations I'd like to use move command instead of copy.  I could make it work for 1D dynamic arrays, but for 2D or higher I could not. For the second dimension, after issued move(A,B,size) the elements of array B point to the same memory address of elements of array A, i.e. B references A.  In fact I want to work with B separetely of A.   See my code :

```
program ProjArrayMove;

    {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

    {$R *.res}

    uses
      System.SysUtils;

    Type

         Arrayint   = Tarray<Integer>;
         Arrayreal  = TArray<Real>;
         MatrixInt  = Array of Arrayreal;
    var
        vectorA, vectorB : Arrayint;
        matA, matB       : MatrixInt;
        idx,idy          : integer;
    begin
         TRY
           // =============== TESTING WITH 1D DYNAMIC ARRAYS OF SIMPLE TYPES ==================
              Writeln('==============================================================');
              Writeln('========= TESTING 1-DIMENSION DYNAMIC ARAYS ==================');
              Writeln('===============================================================');

              readln;
              Writeln('------- Fills Vector A ----------------------------');
              SetLength(vectorA,5);
              for idx :=0 to 4 do
              begin
                    vectorA[idx] := (idx+1) * 10;
                    Writeln('VectorA : [' + idx.tostring + ']  '  +
                              Format('Address : %p  [%d]' ,[PPointer(@VectorA), VectorA[idx] ]) );
              end;

              readln;
              Writeln('--------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Moves VectorA to VectorB ------------------');

              SetLength(VectorB,Length(vectorA));
              Move(VectorA[0],VectorB[0],SizeoF(VectorA[0]) * Length(VectorA));
              for idx :=0 to 4 do
                    Writeln('VectorB : [' + idx.tostring + ']  '  +
                              Format('Address : %p  [%d]' ,[PPointer(@VectorB), VectorB[idx] ]) );

              readln;
              Writeln('---------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Changes VectorB contents  ------------------');

              for idx :=0 to 4 do
              begin
                    vectorB[idx] := (idx+1) * 200;
                    Writeln('VectorB : [' + idx.tostring + ']  '  +
                              Format('Address : %p  [%d]' ,[PPointer(@VectorB), VectorB[idx] ]) );
              end;

              readln;
              Writeln('--------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Checking Vector A  ------------------------');

              for idx :=0 to 4 do
                    Writeln('VectorA : [' + idx.tostring + ']  '  +
                              Format('Address : %p  [%d]' ,[PPointer(@VectorA), VectorA[idx] ]) );
              Writeln;
              Writeln('CONCLUSION : ===>>  MOVE command works fine for 1-Dimension Dynamic Arrays!');
              readln;


    //=========================== TESTING WITH MATRIX 2D DYNAMIC ARRAYS OF SIMPLE TYPES ==================

              Writeln('===============================================================');
              Writeln('========= TESTING 2-DIMENSIONS DYNAMIC ARAYS ==================');
              Writeln('===============================================================');
              readln;
              Writeln('------ Fills MatrixA -----------------------------');
              SetLength(matA,5,2);
              for idx :=0 to 4 do
                 for idy := 0 to 1 do
                 begin
                       matA[idx][idy] := (idx +1) * (idy +1);
                        Writeln('Mat A : [' + idx.tostring + '][' + idy.tostring +']  '  +
                                  Format('Address : %p  [%f]' ,[PPointer(@matA[idx][idy]), matA[idx][idy] ] ));
                 end;

              readln;
              Writeln('-------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Move MatrixA to MatrixB ------------------');

              SetLength(matB,length(matA));
              //move(matA[0],MatB[0],Sizeof(matA[0]) * length(matA));
              move(matA,MatB,Sizeof(matA[0]) * length(matA));
              for idx :=0 to 4 do
              begin
                   Setlength(MatB[idx],length(matA[idx]));
                   //Move(matA[idx][0],matB[idx][0],sizeof(matB[idx][0]) * length(matB[idx]) );
                   Move(matA[idx],matB[idx],sizeof(matB[idx][0]) * length(matB[idx]) );
                   for idy := 0 to 1 do
                   begin
                          Writeln('Mat B : [' + idx.tostring + '][' + idy.tostring +']  '  +
                                  Format('Address : %p  [%f]' ,[PPointer(@matB[idx][idy]), matB[idx][idy] ] ));

                   end;
              end;

              readln;

              Writeln('-------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Change MatrixB content  ------------------');
              readln;

              for idx :=0 to 4 do
                 for idy := 0 to 1 do
                 begin
                      matB[idx][idy] := 100.5 * (idx+1) * (idy +1);
                      Writeln('Mat B : [' + idx.tostring + '][' + idy.tostring +']  '  +
                              Format('Address : %p  [%f]' ,[PPointer(@matB[idx][idy]), matB[idx][idy] ] ));
                 end;

              Writeln('-------------------------------------------------');
              Writeln('------ Checking Matrix A ------------------------');
              readln;

              for idx :=0 to 4 do
                 for idy := 0 to 1 do
                        Writeln('Mat A : [' + idx.tostring + '][' + idy.tostring +']  '  +
                                 Format('Address : %p  [%f]' ,[PPointer(@matA[idx][idy]), matA[idx][idy] ] ));


              Writeln;
              Writeln('CONCLUSION : ===>>  MOVE command DOES NOT WORK on 2-Dimensions Dynamic Arrays!');
              readln;

          except
            on E: Exception do
                 begin
                       Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
                       readln;
                 end;
          end;
    end.
```

Is there something wrong or missing in move command for the second dimension?

Thanks !

Comment: As you say, you cannot use a single `Move` to copy a two-dimensional dynamic array, since the outermost array only contains an array of pointers to the inner arrays. If you need performance, especially when it comes to copying, I suggest you store your data in a single one-dimensional array, in row-major order, say. You could put this in a record type with a default two-parameter array property that automatically gives you `MyData[Y, X]` indexing. This simply reads the element `Y*n + X` in the underlying one-dimensional array, where `n` is the fixed width of the matrix.

Comment: If you have a lot of 2D arrays. you should definitely write a class to encapsulate them (backed by a 1D array, as Andreas said). If you use them as matrices (in the mathematical sense), you should even use a library (like [this one](https://github.com/mikerabat/mrmath)).

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the comments.  I'll think about it, for sure.

Comment: @Oivier, I'll take a look at this library as well , maybe it is an alternative for what I'm doing here. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: @Olivier how does that library's performance compare with openblas for mkl?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know but it uses a lot of assembly with SSE/AVX instructions, so it should be fast.

Comment: @Olivier That's really no guarantee of performance. To get the performance levels of openblas / MKL you need to tune for different processor architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems start here:

```
Move(matA, matB, Sizeof(matA[0]) * Length(matA));
```

You are passing a dynamic array to `Move`. A dynamic array is implemented as a pointer to the first element of the array. You are therefore overwriting the pointer.

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
Move(matA[0], matB[0], Sizeof(matA[0]) * Length(matA));
```

But you don't want to do that either. That's using `Move` on a managed type, which is exactly the same mistake that you made in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071389/).

In fact if you just remove that line of code it should work. Note I've not checked in detail so there may be other defects.

Your code is really extremely complex, and it's very hard to see what is going on. At least some of your problems are due to your code being so obfuscated. Try to stop putting huge amounts of code into a single procedure. Split the code up into smaller parts, and then glue these smaller parts together in a driver routine.

You want to use a function like this:

```
function CloneMatrixInt(const matrix: array of ArrayInt): MatrixInt;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(matrix));
  for i := 0 to High(Result) do
    Result[i] := Copy(matrix[i]);
end;
```

Notice that this is essentially identical to the answer to your previous question. Why is that?

You need to stop thinking of `MatrixInt` as a multidimensional array. It's not. It's just an array. It's an array whose elements are in turn also arrays. Technically it is a jagged array. But you just need to think of it as a single dimensional array.

So the function to clone it operates as follows:

1. Allocate the destination array.
2. Loop over the destination array cloning each element from the source array.

That's exactly the same process as in your previous question. There we had an array of record with a function to clone that record. But because we had separated the two tasks of cloning the outer array from cloning the elements of the array, the resulting code is essentially identical.

Now imagine you had an array of `MatrixInt`. Let's say

```
type
  ArrayMatrixInt = array of MatrixInt;
```

Well, clone that like this:

```
function CloneArrayMatrixInt(const arrayMatrix: array of MatrixInt): ArrayMatrixInt;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(arrayMatrix));
  for i := 0 to High(Result) do
    Result[i] := CloneMatrixInt(matrix[i]);
end;
```

Guess what, the exact same code as before!

Given this question, and your previous one, can I please suggest that you refrain from trying to use `Move` to solve all problems. There's no reason to suggest that any of the problems you are encountering are going to be solved by using `Move`.

One final note. Jagged arrays are expensive to allocate because they require multiple allocations. They are also inefficient to operate on because they are not stored contiguously. Delphi lacks a multidimensional array type, and if ultimate performance is required then you may be best to implement multidimensional array type.

Comment: the move sintaxe you suggested was already tried as you can see in commented part of my code, but it did not work either. The inner array is a managed type, that is what you meant here , right ?  Your examples and explanations are clear.  I'll have to digest them and rethink the way I'm using dynamic arrays operations and data structures. Great help, thank you!

Comment: "the move syntax you suggested was already tried as you can see in commented part of my code, but it did not work either." That's actually what I said in my answer. All dynamic arrays are managed types.

Comment: So, I'm curious, why are trying to use `Move` at all?

Comment: yeah, clear now regarding managed types and dynamic arrays. I'm trying to use move in order to speed up dynamic arrays copy of slices or entire array.  Dos it make sense for you ?

Comment: How do you know that is a bottleneck in your program? If you haven't profiled to prove that then your are likely wasting your time.

Comment: that is a good point , thanks for remind me!  In fact I've measured the whole program functions and I've made improvements where  I could see there was a room for that without change design or data structures.  The slowest parts now are those related to copy arrays or slices of it , that is why I expected move would help me.

Comment: How did you perform these measurements?

Comment: in a simple and direct way I used to do, before each procedure that perform few and specific tasks I put stopwatch.create and at the end a stopwatch.stop and then capture the time. The ones presented high time, I investigated code and change , if possible, by different constructions or logic. Traverse and copy long dyn arrays were parts taking long to execute.   Do you have any suggestions on a differente way to measure ?  Thnks.

Comment: You aren't measuring what think you are. Quite likely the heap allocation is far more significant. There are a few profilers about, none that reliable in my opinion. I tend to use a crude sample based approach. Let the program run, and the break into it and inspect the call stack. Do that a few times and if the same function comes up repeatedly, that's your bottleneck.

Comment: it seems an interesting method, I'll check that on this way.  Thank you David.